# MS Access - record level security

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access database where all the users will be in the same group, except a few. I don't need to restrict certain objects from users. Instead, I need to give the current user write capabilities to his record and its related records only and read-only capabilities to all other records. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, be it Access, SQL server or Oracle, the restriction of rows to a single user is not built in. This means you have to build some type of interface in which you grab/use the users Logged on ID (their network pc id, or say prompt for a user + password). Then you when a form loads you have to restrict the records to that one given user. There are many ways to do this and they are all standard approaches to filtering or restricting data. However "YOU" have to build and write such code into the forms. You could perhaps base the form on a query with a expression (VBA or macro TempVars) that limits the records returned to the given user.

So you have to “cook” and “code” this ability for most any database. You thus also need to code to “save” the user name who created the record. This coding requirement as noted is required for most systems when looking to restrict data to single rows and such features are not generally built into the database system. You also likely need to restrict and prevent users from opening the database and seeing the table view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Albert! I ended up doing something similar to what you suggested. I wrote some code that disabled and locked the listbox if the ID of the NetworkUser didn't match the ID of the selected item. They can read anything but they can't write to anything. Seems to be working great. Thanks, again, for your input.

Comment: Postgres now has Row Level Security built in.  
You decide what algorithm allows a user to see a record in a table, e.g. (mytable.rowowner = CurrentUser)
All read / write access to that table has to pass the RLS filter.